# How to filter NullString In Java

Tags: java

I'm new to Java, working with the following class:

```
import java.lang.management.ManagementFactory;
import java.lang.management.ThreadMXBean;
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.nio.ByteOrder;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;

public class Utils {

    public static String[] fitlerNullString(String[] array) {
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        for(String c : array) {
            if(c != null && c.length() > 0) {
                list.add(c);
            }
        }
        return list.toArray(new String[list.size()]);
    }
}
```

When I call this, `filternullstring` function returns nothing.
Here is my code:

```
private static Options options = new Options();
public static void main(String[] args) {
    options.addOption("acom", "com", true, "abc");
    options.addOption("bcom", "command", true, "def");
    options.addOption("p", "play", true, "ghi");
    options.addOption("h", "help", false, "jkl");
    try {
                   String audioCOM = "";
        String commandCOM = "";
        args = Utils.fitlerNullString(args);
        CommandLine cmd = parser.parse(options, args);
if (cmd.hasOption("acom") ) {
            audioCOM = cmd.getOptionValue("com");;
        }
        if (cmd.hasOption("bcom") ) {
            commandCOM = cmd.getOptionValue("command");;    
        }
    }
}
```

Please guide me.  Where have I made a mistake?  Please check my code again as there is still no result.

Comment: Are you really supplying anything(args) through command-line when doing `java MainClass args`?

Comment: If it's returning a blank array, then that would suggest that every argument is blank or null. What arguments are you passing into the application?

Comment: you have to giv some arguments ... so that it wil filter properly

Comment: no i m not passing anything in args through command line

Comment: that would explain your problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about something like this-

```
 public static String[] fitlerNullString(final String[] array) {

       // Return the original array if null or empty
       if(array == null || array.length == 0) {
           return array;
       }

       // Create a new array with the size of the passed array
       String[] strings = new String[array.length];
       // For keeping track of indices of the new array
       int ctr = 0;

       for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {

           // If null or empty continue to the next item if any
           if(array[i] == null || array[i].isEmpty()) {
               continue;
           }

           // Otherwise add and increase the counter
           strings[ctr] = array[i];
           ctr ++;

       }

       // return the array
       return Arrays.copyOfRange(strings, 0, ctr);

   }
```

Test:

```
String[] vals = new String[3];
vals[0] = "Apple";
vals[1] = null;
vals[2] = "Banana";

String a[] = fitlerNullString(vals);

for(int j = 0; j < a.length; j++){
    System.out.print(a[j] + "\t");
}
```

Comment: sajal i check your code result is same nothing return i want like if (cmd.hasOption("acom") ) {
            audioCOM = cmd.getOptionValue("com");;
        }
        if (cmd.hasOption("bcom") ) {
            commandCOM = cmd.getOptionValue("command");;    
        }
    }
}

Answer (score 1):

I think you should use the Guava library for working with `String` objects.

For your question there is a simple answer there: `Strings.isNullOrEmpty(stringObject)`

If you don't like Guava there is ApacheCommons and many more. Just don't reinvent the wheel.

Answer (score 0):

You can check like this also, Use **[isEmpty()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#isEmpty%28%29)**

*No extra library needed*.

```
if(Strings != null && !Strings.isEmpty())
```

Comment: i want to get result like this if (cmd.hasOption("a") ) {
    audioCOM = cmd.getOptionValue("com");;
   } but cmd return null

Comment: @user2971145 Wat is this `parser.parse(options, args)`

Answer (score 0):

You can use "Guava preconditions". [LINK](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/PreconditionsExplained)

Answer (score 0):

You must to know, that when you start Java application, system array args provided by jvm and doesn't contains empty or null strings. Anyway, in general you can filter array this way:

```
List<String> argsList = new LinkedList<String>(Arrays.asList(args));
argsList.removeAll(Arrays.asList("", null));
```

Answer (score 0):

fitlerNullString() code should work fine, argument you are passing may be not containing null values .